# Extract Url from a string though regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Trying to extract all urls from a string an store it in an array

Using the below regex:

```
/<a href=([^>]*)>ss URL<\/a>/g
```

for the string:

```
 <a href='https://zzzz' target="_blank">ss URL</a>
```

but i am getting the output with target blank:

```
`'https://zzzz' target="_blank"`
```

Comment: just match the quoted url, not all the bolierplate html... ( `[^ '"]+` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't. Just use DOM methods to get them. First, we create a temporary div and then set it's inner html to that of the input string. The we can go through the `<a>` and return their `href` property using `Array.map`

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerHTML = str;
var urls = [].map.call(elem.querySelectorAll('a'), function(a){
    return a.innerText.toLowerCase() == "ss url" ? a.href : "";
}).filter(String);
```

Comment: @TabraizAli I know it is a string.

Comment: @TabraizAli it is more fail-proof and using regex to parse html is an invitation to Satan.

Comment: @TabraizAli if it can be done through DOM go for DOM method as `regex` solution can fail with slightest change in `html`.

Comment: @AmitJoki how do i select only links inside ss url as mentioned in question

Comment: @TabraizAli like my edit. Just use a ternary operator and filter the rest

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='([^>']*)'[^>]*>ss URL<\/a>
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/11